# How do I generate a publishable lib in NX without bundling and multiple entry points?

Tags: module, package, tsc, nx.dev

I started using NX recently.  I have been trying to figure out their generators for a specific setup.  I have a lib of react components that should be publishable.  Due to constraints on an existing code base being ported across, I require a publishable package that has multiple entry points (I am using package.json's exports feature to do this in the past).  However I cant find a generator setup that pulls this off.

If I use the standard 'npx nx g @nx/react:lib', it forces me to use a bundler.  I do not want bundled code in a publishable library package.  Why? Just why?

If I use something like: 'npm nx g lib' and choose tsc as the compiler, then it forces me to have a 'main' entry in my setup, which stops me from being able to have multiple entry points with 'exports'.

I really don't know what I'm supposed to use to solve this.